# Angular watchCollection absolutely doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, watch

CONTROLLER:

```
 app.controller('SettingsController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.openingtimes = {
        "times": [
        {"id":1,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělí","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:00"},
        {"id":2,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělíadas","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:02"},
        {"id":3,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělí","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:00"},
        {"id":4,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělísf","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:00"}
        ]};

    $scope.$watchCollection('openingtimes.times', function () {
        console.log("work");
    });

});
```

VIEW:

```
<div class="angular" ng-controller="SettingsController">

<div ng-repeat="time in openingtimes.times">

    <input type="text" ng-model="time.name_of_day"/> {{ time.name_of_day }} : {{ time.open_from | openingTime }} - {{ time.open_to | openingTime }}

</div>
```

everything works fine when I type to input model is changing becuase I see it here: {{ time.name_of_day}} but controller doesn't log anything! I tried almost everything and still nothing... I have in console only one log "work" and it's after refresh page. But after changing model absolutely nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of the structure of your object - you have an object of arrays of objects... while `$watchCollection` does the following:

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties).

[excerpt from here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

The simplest solution is probably just to set a `$watchCollection` for each object in the array:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('SettingsController', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.openingtimes = {
        "times": [
        {"id":1,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělí","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:00"},
        {"id":2,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělíadas","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:02"},
        {"id":3,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělí","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:00"},
        {"id":4,"day":1,"name_of_day":"Pondělísf","open_from":"13:00","open_to":"16:00"}
        ]};

    for(var i in $scope.openingtimes.times) {
      $scope.$watchCollection('openingtimes.times[' + i + ']', function () {
        console.log("work");
      });
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="angular" ng-app="app" ng-controller="SettingsController">
<div ng-repeat="time in openingtimes.times">

    <input type="text" ng-model="time.name_of_day"/> {{ time.name_of_day }} : {{ time.open_from }} - {{ time.open_to }}

</div>
```

Or, if you're using Angular 1.3+, you can use `$watchGroup` instead.